# Hiding subfolders from users with Windows Server security

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, access-control-list

Using Windows Server 2008.

I would like to allow all users to map to a common network drive and be able to browse it. But, I only want them to be able to see the subfolders they actually have access rights to.
Is this doable?

**Example**
I have a share with two folders on it;
\\domain\share\FolderA
\\domain\share\FolderB

With three different security groups, I would like to map a network drive for all three to \\domain\share.
However, for group1, I want them to only be able to see FolderA, group2 should only see FolderB and group3 should see both.
I am not just talking about denying access to the actual folder, which is easy enough, I don't want the user to even be able to see that the folder exists.

In other words, when group 1 logs in and do "dir n:\" they should see
 N:\FolderA

When group 2 logs in, they should see
 N:\FolderB

and when group 3 logs in they should see
 N:\Folder A
 N:\Folder B

**My half-baked solution**
If I completely block access to the root then I can't map a drive to it. I can give everyone the traverse right which then allows the user to map a drive. However, if a member of group1 or group2 tries to go to "N:\" they get an access denied error. If they go to N:\FolderA (for group1) then it works.

So, that sort of works, but it would be nicer if the user could actually browse to N:\ and just only see the subfolders they have access to.

I am pretty sure I have seen this done but not sure how to do it myself. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most certainly you can do this natively in windows Server 2008. Have a read here:

http://blog.stealthpuppy.com/windows/access-based-enumeration-in-windows-server

Comment: Happy to be of service.

Comment: There is even an addon for Windows Server 2003 users to enable Access Based Enumeration (at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04A563D9-78D9-4342-A485-B030AC442084)! (for those searching) I must say, it works wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

This still isn't possible in Windows...I was hoping it would be in 2008 but I think it is a limit of the current version of NTFS itself.

What you are talking about is a great feature of Netware that never bothered to come to fruition (yet) in NTFS.

See here (still after all these years):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303758

I'd love to be wrong on this...so hopefully someone will chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Second TheCleaner here.  This was a great feature of Novell Netware that never got implemented in Windows.  Why bother the user with 50 folders they can't access and one they can.

Comment: I take it all back!